# Properties how pass them array value

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, properties

I want to ask how pass a array value to the properties.

Always at first should be 'properties name', but I have got a lot repetable names. So I want give them to the Array. How I can pass them ? If I put them in this sort of code i get a lot of errors in Console. here is my code in properties text:

```
PropertyPaneTextField(this.properties.linkArray[0], {
            label: "Kafel nr 1"
          }),
```

I need to pass a lot of values but if I tried put this I getting a lot of errors. Please help me.

Comment: It works when I set up "PropertyPaneTextField('Propertie Name', {
            label: "Kafel nr 1"
          }),"

Comment: this.properties.linkArray[0] should be a string

Comment: it is a string, but it give me error.

Comment: I added "this.properties.linkArray[0].toString(),", but still I getting a lot of errors.

Comment: But why arey you storing it in array? Are all property names in your array only?

Comment: Because 'propertyName' is used in your render methods to get the value from the property pane using this.properties.propertyName . So it is recommended to have a hard coded name to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Because I have got a lot of repatable column names store like properties. It's are "Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Namer5 ....Name16".

Comment: Property name should be unique for each property

Comment: My Booss told me that it should be a array...

Comment: Yes i know so they are different Name with name "Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Namer5 ....Name16"

Comment: @harshalgite and it is unique, because it showing 1 element on array.

Comment: I think you need to redesign your logic.

Comment: ok but how. how culd I store in properties 16 links, their names, and their icons ? I must create and I done 48 properties ?

Comment: and how put them into the array in array I can call them by index. If I have got link1, link2, link3 I can't do this.

Comment: See what I'm trying to say is, react uses the props in it's render method to refer to the changes made to the properties in the property pane. That has to be unique and known to react v-dom an that is the reason it has to be declared in properties. Instead of defining linkArray inside properties, you can declare it as an array outside and create a function to push property dynamically to the "groupFields"

Comment: But how could I do it ? Could You please give a sample of code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Grzegorz,

You may want to look at the PropertyFieldCollectionData control from
[@pnp/spfx-property-controls](https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldCollectionData/).

You can find more information here: https://sharepoint.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldCollectionData/

You can also look at the [source code](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/tree/master/src/propertyFields/collectionData) if you need to understand how it works.

I hope this helps?

Comment: I using this controls. So that's why I can't use this.